# Exporting multiple dataframes with groupby clause into one csv file

Tags: python, group-by

I have a table like this:

```
Student Board ID      School     Grade by School    Grade in Boards
1                      ABC          A                           A
2                      ABC          B                           C
3                      XYZ          C                           C
4                      ABC          D                           D
5                      GHI          E                           E
```

and so on.

Question:

School wise list of cases where both grades are same.(School grade=A and CBSE grade =A as well and so on)

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame("School grades List.csv")
aa = df['Grade by School'].eq('A') & workbook['Grade in Boards'].eq('A')
aa1=aa.groupby(df['School']).sum()

df = pd.DataFrame("School grades List.csv")
bb = df['Grade by School'].eq('B') & workbook['Grade in Boards'].eq('B')
bb1=bb.groupby(df['School']).sum()

and so on....
```

**What I want:**

Exporting all these different dataframes to one single csv file with a blank line in between 2 dataframes.

```
School Name    #Cases where both grades are A
ABC               1.0
XYZ               2.0
GHI               10.0  

School Name    #Cases where both grades are B
ABC               2.0
XYZ               4.0
GHI               30.0  

School Name    #Cases where both grades are C
ABC               19.0
XYZ               21.0
GHI               11.0
```

and so on in one csv file

Tried so far: As per comments included header=True and rename option but no luck

```
[IN]
aa1.to_csv('aa1.csv', header=True)
[OUT]

    School     0
    ABC       1.0
    XYZ       2.0
    GHI       10.0
```

Can anyone help with **how to get the column names on top of each file**(even if we are not able to combine multiple files to 1 csv).

**Output with rename is as follows:**

```
[IN]
 aa1.rename(index={0:'School', 1: 'Cases where both grades are A'})

[OUT]
   School      0
    ABC       1.0
    XYZ       2.0
    GHI       10.0
```

For example each file should look like this:

```
School Name    #Cases where both grades are A
    ABC       1.0
    XYZ       2.0
    GHI       10.0
```

etc.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you read Pandas to_csv docs? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

Comment: I have tried this:

aa1.to_csv("aa1file.csv")
bb1.to_csv("bb1file.csv")

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a list of dataframes and then concate on axis=0, Try below code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [aa1,bb1]
df = pd.concat(data, ignore_index=True)
df.to_csv('file.csv', header=True, index=False)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi I tried this. I am getting a list of 0,0,10 etc. School names are not reflecting in the combined file file.csv. However individual files aa1, bb1 etc. had school names and sum of values(ABC   1.0, XYZ   2.0 etc.)

Comment: Hi result still the same.  School names not reflecting

Answer (score 1):

To export headers use [header=True](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) when calling to_csv().

As for combining everything into one file, there might be a better way, but, if you call to_csv() without passing a filename it returns a string with the csv, and you might build a string with all the csv (adding blank lines in between).

Comment: Hi in using header=True in the code : aa1.to_csv("aa1.csv", header=True)
I am getting below column names:
School    0

How can I change the 2nd column name (sum column) to be something other than 0. I want the second column name to be cases where students got A grade lets say.

Comment: Dataframe.rename should do it https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html

Comment: Tried this
aa1.rename(index={0:'School', 1: 'Cases where both grades are A'})
aa1.to_csv("aa1.csv", header=True)

However it doesnt work on groupby clause it seems.